# How to store dates in MongoDB and use them in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I'd like to store birth dates in my application's Mongo database. Obviously a stored birth date has no associated time. I'd like to then display the date in my AngularJS-based UI in the format MM/dd/yy (e.g., 04/18/80). So, I'll pass the date through an Angular filter:

```
{{dateOfBirth | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}
```

I've come up with the following date storage solutions, but I'm not super happy with any of them:

1. Simply store dates as simple strings; e.g., "1980-04-18". But then, I probably can't use comparison operators (<, >, <=, >=) when querying dates.
2. Store dates as ISODate objects in Mongo. The UI would receive the date as "1980-04-18T00-00-00Z" (I store dates in UTC). But I think this would then cause timezone-related headaches, as 1980-04-17 (one day prior) might be displayed for US users.

I know JavaScript's Date object always includes times, which makes things difficult.

Is there another solution I'm missing?

Comment: Can store the normal date time object and just trim the time when you display it. (Im a big fan of momentJS when it comes to dealing with dates in JS)

Comment: How would you trim the time in Angular, and at what point in the process would you do so?

Comment: You can do it right in your `repeat` method (assuming you're using `ng-repeat`). `{{formatTime(item.timeStamp)}}` and then have a method `$scope.formatTime = function(utcDate) { return moment(utcDate).format("MMddYYYY"); }`

Comment: Or if you have a service returning the data to your controller, run a `forEach` over the array and format the timestamp there, then return the data to the controller and repeat it. Either way, got some possibilities

Comment: Okay cool. Still, though, if a birthdate is stored as ISODate("1980-04-18T00-00-00Z") in Mongo, and I'm in the -05:00 timezone, then won't Moment.js display 04/17/1980 (instead of 04/18/1980)?

Comment: Nope, moment will take care of that for you (so much time saved) - that library has saved me hours of figuring out date logic